# HDFS configuration & what is the user directory for?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am currently "playing around" with Hadoop in a VM (CDH4.1.3 image from cloudera). What I am wondering about is the following (and the documentation did not really help me in that regard).

Following the tutorial, I would format a NameNode first - OK, that is already done if one uses the cloudera image. Likewise the HDFS file structure is already present. In the hdfs-site.xml the datanode data dir is set to:

```
/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data
```

which is obviously where the blocks are supposed to be copied to in a real distributed setting. In the cloudera tutorial, one is told to create hdfs "home directories" for each user (`/users/<username>`), which I do not understand what they are for. Are they just for local test-runs in a single-node setup?
Say I really had petabytes of data on type not fitting into my local storage. This data would have to be distributed straight away, rendering a local "home directory" entirely useless.

Could someone tell me, just to give me an intuition, how a real Hadoop workflow with massive data would look like? What kind of distinct nodes would I have running for a start?

There's the master (JobTracker) with its slave file (where would I put that) allowing the master to resolve all the DataNodes. Then there is my NameNode that keeps track of where the block IDs are stored. The DataNodes are also carry TaskTracker responsibility. In the config files, the NameNode's URI is included -- am I correct so far? Then there is still the `${user.name}` variable in the configuration which apparently, if I understood it right, has something to do with WebHDFS, which would also be great if someone could explain to me. In the running examples, the directions tend to be hardcoded to

```
/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/1/dfs/data, /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/2/dfs/data and so on.
```

So, back to the example: Say, I have my tape and want to import data into my HDFS (and I am required to stream data into the filesystem because I lack the local storage to save it locally on a single machine). Where would I start with the migration process? On an arbitrary DataNode? On the NameNode that distributes the chunks? After all, I cannot assume the data just to "be there", because the name node has to be aware of the block IDs.

It would be great if someone could shortly elaborate on these topics:

1. What is the home directory really for?
2. Do I migrate data to the home directory first and to the real distributed system afterwards?
3. How does WebHDFS work and what role does it play with regards to the user.name variable
4. How would I migrate "big data" into my HDFS on the fly - or even if it's not big data, how do I populate my file system in a proper way (meaning, that the chunks get randomly distributed across the cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the home directory really for?

You have a small confusion here. Just like /home exists for local filesystems on Linux, where users are given their own storage space, /users is a home mount ON the HDFS (Distributed FS). The tutorial needs you to administratively create a home directory for the user you wish to later be running data loads and queries as, such that they get adequate permissions and storage access onto the HDFS. The tutorial is not asking you to create these directories locally.

> Do I migrate data to the home directory first and to the real distributed system afterwards?

I believe my above answer should clarify this for you. You should create your home directory on the HDFS, and then load all your data inside of that directory.

> How does WebHDFS work and what role does it play with regards to the user.name variable

WebHDFS is one of the various ways to access HDFS. Regular clients to talk to HDFS require use of Java APIs. WebHDFS (and also HttpFs) techniques were added to HDFS to let other languages have their own set of APIs by providing a REST front-end to HDFS. WebHDFS allows user-authentication, to help persist the permission and security models.

> How would I migrate "big data" into my HDFS on the fly - or even if it's not big data, how do I populate my file system in a proper way (meaning, that the chunks get randomly distributed across the cluster?

The large part of problem HDFS solves for you is that of managing distribution of data. When loading files or data streams to HDFS (via CLI tools, sinks from Apache Flume, etc.), the blocks are spread in an ideal distribution by HDFS itself, and the chunking is managed by it as well. All you need to do is use the user-side regular FileSystem style APIs and forget about what goes where underneath - its all managed for you.

Comment: thanks for clarifying! i had them mounted on the HDFS, but i did not really get why they are required, considering that there are datanode dirs anyway. cloud you maybe elaborate on what the user.name variable is used for (i just want to make sure that it is actually supposed to be in the config instead of some hardcoded folder name)? my guess is that it has something to do with running HDFS with user-specific data on the cluster, correct? after all, the name node directories are user-specific as well (meaning, it is a rudimentary system for allowing permission only to the data owner)? thanks!

Comment: Hi @sim - The "user.name" is a special JVM system property that gets auto-set to the current user executing the JVM. That is, in any java program, the return result of System.getProperty("user.name") would by default be the user that actually ran that program.

In Hadoop Configuration classes, we support substituting values of certain properties by letting users pass JVM level properties (via -D on the JVM opts), and one of the default properties supported is ${user.name} which we end up leveraging to automatically construct user-specific paths or data for user-specific operations.